# Print l1.processor in a method

Tags: java

I want to print the `l1.processor` (an attribute of object l1) in a method but I can't do that. Here's my code:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Laptop {

    String processor;
    int gen;
    int ram;
    int hdd;
    int ssd;

    void output(){
        System.out.println(l1.processor);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Laptop l1 = new Laptop();
        Laptop l2 = new Laptop();
        Laptop l3 = new Laptop();

        l1.processor = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Processor: " + l1.processor);

    }
}
```

Comment: and what does, " I can't do that" mean?

Comment: You should create getter method for each of the attributes of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `output` method is wrong. Since the variable `processor` is global, you can change it like this:

```
void output(){
    System.out.println(processor);
}
```

Or, pass an instance of `Laptop` and keep the method body the way it was before.

```
void output(Laptop l1){
    System.out.println(l1.processor);
}
```

Of course, `l1` is not a good variable name.